# Hybrid DotNet Core/.NET Framework Build with MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

`dotnet msbuild`

from the sln directory works

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

from the solution directory works

I don't want VS 2017 to have to be installed on a build machine, so I installed "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017" from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe
```

bombs out on every single project in the sln with the error:

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

In truth - it doesn't exist on disk. It only exists in the VS subfolder at

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks

I have manually tried installing the .NET 4.6 SDK, the .NET Core 1.0 SDK, and .NET Core 1.0.1 SDK (both x86 and x64 versions).

Is there any way to make MSBuild function correctly or is it just irrepairably broken like much else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the sdks folder from the dotnet core install to the msbuild tools install directory.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found now is to create a compile configuration where I target all the .NetCore and .net Standard projects and an other for all .Net projects (or simply use the release config).

Then I use MsBuild twice to build.

MSBuild.exe MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=DotNetCore

MSBuild.exe MySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release

It works for VS2017 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The Build Tools installer does not currently support .NET Core workloads. At the moment, you must install Visual Studio on your build machines (or, as you note, install the .NET Core SDK and invoke `dotnet msbuild` instead of `msbuild.exe`).

This issue is tracked in MSBuild's GitHub repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1697.

Comment: Another option is to copy the sdks folder from the dotnet core install to the msbuild tools install

Comment: Also using dotnet build isn't an okay option because it doesn't filter to a specific sln file